# Redshift view all tables across all schemas

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift database that contains multiple schemas. Each schema contains multiple tables.
I need to search for a particular table but I don't know in which schema it resides.
Is there a query I can use to get the names of all tables within all schemas?

Expected o/p:

```
Schema 1  table 1
Schema 1  table 2
Schema 2  table 1
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use `information_schema.tables` system table to get tables and its schema details. *Note that, you may not have permission to access this table*. Ask your database administrator to execute following query and get details.

```
select t.table_schema, t.table_name
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_name = 'test1' -- Your Table Name
order by t.table_name;

 table_schema  | table_name
---------------+------------
 public        | test1
 sample_schema | test1
```

Comment: Is there any way to get empty schema in redshift?